# How to get the image from sqlite by imageid in it?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have use baseadapter for retrieve imageid,title,fromtime,totime.i can't set the imageid to my imageview

my code is follows:

```
public class SQliteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> Imageid;
    ArrayList<String> Title;
    ArrayList<String> fromtimer;
    ArrayList<String> totimer;
    //   ArrayList<String> UserSubject ;


    public SQliteAdapter(
            Context context2,
            ArrayList<String> Imageid,
            ArrayList<String> Title,
            ArrayList<String> fromtimer,
            ArrayList<String> totimer
            // ArrayList<String> subject
    )
    {

        this.context = context2;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.fromtimer = fromtimer;
        this.totimer =  totimer;
        //this.UserSubject = subject ;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Imageid.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.showlist, null);

            holder = new Holder();

            holder.image = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.showimage);
            holder.title = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.title1);
            holder.fromtimer = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.fromtimer);
            holder.totimer = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.totimer);
            // holder.textviewsubject = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.textViewSUBJECT);

            child.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        holder.image.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(Imageid.get(position)));
        holder.title.setText(Title.get(position));
        holder.fromtimer.setText(fromtimer.get(position));
        holder.totimer.setText(totimer.get(position));
        // holder.textviewsubject.setText(UserSubject.get(position));

        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        ImageView image;
        TextView title,fromtimer,totimer;
        //TextView textviewphone_number;
        //  TextView textviewsubject;
    }
```

My Main Activity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ImageView control;


    ArrayList<String> sName = null;
    ArrayList<String> sImageID = null;
    ArrayList<String> iFrom = null;
    ArrayList<String> iTo = null;


    ListView list;
    List<Program> rowItems;
    int  iImageId;
    String sTitle,sFrom,sTo ;
    SQLiteDatabase db;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        db =openOrCreateDatabase("MukilProgram", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proname(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ImageID INTEGER,Title TEXT,FromTiming INTEGER,ToTiming INTEGER);");

        rowItems = new ArrayList<Program>();
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            Program item = new Program(images[i], titles[i],fromtime[i],totime[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }




        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM proname;");


        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        final ProgramAdapter adapter = new ProgramAdapter(this,rowItems, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Program rowItem = (Program) adapter.getItem(i);

            iImageId = rowItem.getImageId();
            sTitle = rowItem.getTitle();
            sFrom = rowItem.getFromtime();
            sTo  = rowItem.getTotime();

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO proname (ImageID,Title,FromTiming,ToTiming) VALUES("+ iImageId + ",'" + sTitle + "','"+sFrom+"','"+sTo+"');");
            //list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


        media = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mukil_master_jingle);


        final Cursor cView = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM proname WHERE FromTiming <= time('now', 'localtime')\n" + "" +
                "AND ToTiming >= time('now', 'localtime')\n", null);
        if (cView.getCount() > 0) {

            sImageID = new ArrayList<String>();
            sName = new ArrayList<String>();
            iFrom = new ArrayList<String>();
            iTo = new ArrayList<String>();



            while (cView.moveToNext()) {

                sImageID.add(cView.getString(0));
                sName.add(cView.getString(1));
                iFrom.add(cView.getString(2));
                iTo.add(cView.getString(3));

                SQliteAdapter sqliteadapter = new SQliteAdapter(MainActivity.this,sImageID,sName,iFrom,iTo);
                list.setAdapter(sqliteadapter);
            }

        }
```

Please help me..

Comment: Where your Images are saved? How you are saving Image Ids

Comment: in my main activity in String [ ] images

Comment: sorry int[ ] image

Comment: Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.ipadikku_idhayam,
            R.drawable.akilam_360,
            R.drawable.cine_pattarai,
            R.drawable.palsuvai_thoranam,
            R.drawable.pesum_noolagam,
            R.drawable.lollu_cafe,
            R.drawable.kavi_saagaram,
            R.drawable.aa_muthal_akk,
            R.drawable.thiraicholai,
            R.drawable.kathamba_saaral,
            R.drawable.paarkatha_pakkangal,
            R.drawable.pagadi_panna_porom,

    };

Comment: Using Program adapter

Comment: final ProgramAdapter adapter = new ProgramAdapter(this,rowItems, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Program rowItem = (Program) adapter.getItem(i);

            iImageId = rowItem.getImageId();
            sTitle = rowItem.getTitle();
            sFrom = rowItem.getFromtime();
            sTo  = rowItem.getTotime();

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO proname (ImageID,Title,FromTiming,ToTiming) VALUES("+ iImageId + ",'" + sTitle + "','"+sFrom+"','"+sTo+"');");
            //list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

Comment: @Udhya Check answer and try to place all code in question Instead of comments

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on *Resource* Ids, Instead save name of icon or create mapping of *Images* and "Name".

```
// Get name of icon and save it in DB
Resources res = getResources();
String imgName = res=.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.icon);

// Set this resImage on ImageView
int resId = resources.getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", "package_name_of_your_project");
```

Comment: i couldn't understand

Comment: i can't understand

Comment: Right now you are saving id of Image, instead of that, save name of Icon

Comment: where i have to use this coding im new to this so i struggle with this please helpme

Comment: Change your Integer[] images to String[] images. and then put "aa_muthal_akk" instead of R.drawable.aa_muthal_akk. Then in your adapter according to position use this. int resId = resources.getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", "package_name_of_your_project");